# Using a Batch File to send Arguments to MFC Application with a GUI

Tags: user-interface, mfc

I'm looking for the best possible approach to incorporate a batch file to send arguments to the MFC application rather than relying on the GUI interface. Does anyone know the best method to go about doing this?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to process the command line arguments. You now have a couple of answers to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code in my [`InitInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=vs-2019#initinstance) method of my app class:

```
LPWSTR *szArglist = nullptr;
int iNumArgs = 0;
szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &iNumArgs);
if (iNumArgs > 0 && szArglist != nullptr)
{
    for (int iArg = 0; iArg < iNumArgs; iArg++)
    {
        CString strArg(szArglist[iArg]);
        int iDelim = strArg.Find(_T("="));
        if (iDelim != -1)
        {
            CString strParamName = strArg.Left(iDelim);
            CString strParamValue = strArg.Mid(iDelim + 1);
            if (strParamName.CollateNoCase(_T("/lang")) == 0)
            {
                m_strPathLanguageResourceOverride.Format(_T("%sMeetSchedAssist%s.dll"),
                    (LPCTSTR)GetProgramPath(), (LPCTSTR)strParamValue.MakeUpper());

                if (!PathFileExists(m_strPathLanguageResourceOverride))
                    m_strPathLanguageResourceOverride = _T("");
            }
        }
    }

    // Free memory allocated for CommandLineToArgvW arguments.
    LocalFree(szArglist);
}
```

As you can see, I use the [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) method to extract and process the command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

A GUI program can receive command line arguments just like a command line program can.

Your Application class (`CWinApp`, if memory serves) contains a member named `m_lpCmdLine` that contains the command line arguments (if any) in a CString.

If you also want to deal with shell parameters, you'll probably also want to look at `WinApp::ParseCommandLine` and `CCommandLineInfo` (note, if you're dealing with a Wizard-generated program, chances are that `WinApp::ParseCommandLine` is already being called by default).